# Calling wtforms validations conditionally

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am writing a login page using wtforms .The fields are username and password.Below are the two validations defined for two fields.Is there a way to stop the execution of validation function on password field if validation method on username raises exception

```
    def validate_username(self, field):
    # Check if not None for that username!
    print('Inside check_username')
    if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first() is None:
        raise ValidationError(f'Sorry username : {field.data} is not registered!')

    def validate_password(self, field):
       # Below is not the actual code.This method will contain code to check of valid password.
       raise ValidationError(f'Sorry username : {field.data} is not registered!')
```

What is happening right now is both of the above methods are been called which is expected but I don't want to check for password if the username doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop wtforms for trying to validate each field.

I suggest you simply override [validate](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.validate):

```
def validate(self):
    if not super().validate():
        return False

    if User.query.filter_by(username=self.username.data).first() is None:
        self.errors["username"] = f'Sorry username : {self.username.data} is not registered!'
        return False

    if not check_that_password():
        self.errors["password"] = f"Bad password for user {self.username.data}"
        return False

    return True
```